# Rails/rspec: test API with RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rspec, rest-client

I'm currently writing some API tests for the application I'm working on. The tests are written in Hiptest (http://hiptest.net) and then generated transformed to ruby/rspec code.

Each "part" of the API is handled by a different controller, for example in the routes.rb:

```
scope(:path => '/api') do
  resources :actionwords, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :update, :delete], :controller => 'api_actionword'
  resources :scenarios, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :update, :delete], :controller => 'api_scenario'
end
```

The thing is, I am not able to split my tests and include each of them in a suite describing the controller under test (and I can't use `get :some_url`in my tests).

One solution I found was to set the test suite as a feature suite, it opens a browser and I can get the base url and use that for RestClient. But that's pretty dirty and opening the application for every test is a waste of time.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run the test server and access it directly, but I was unable to find how (most responses I found was to use the `rails s` command which is not really what I want, but could be used as a fallback).

Thanks in advance,
Vincent